# Importing modules from more advanced layout

Tags: python, list, bots

Say this is my package layout

```
Package
    :: core
        :: hash
            :: hashgen.py
            :: validate.py
        :: common
            :: classes.py
    :: tools
        :: database_validate.py
    :: bot.py
    :: config.py
```

So if I wanted to import database_validate from tools in bot.py I'd do:

```
from tools import database_validate
```

But for core/hash/hashgen, how would I import that? Because it's slightly longer. I know I can probably just put everything in one file, but I'm curious of how to make it import from a longer folder layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building a package - don't forget the `__init__.py`.  This needs to be in every tree you wish to import from.  In your example it should look like this..

```
Package
    __init__.py
    :: core
        __init__.py
        :: hash
            __init__.py
            :: hashgen.py
            :: validate.py
        :: common
            __init__.py
            :: classes.py
    :: tools
        __init__.py 
       :: database_validate.py
    :: bot.py
    :: config.py
```

Once this is done then you can as phihag suggested

```
from package.core.hash.hashgen import *
```

Although I don't recommend using * per se used here for simplicity.

Check out [this](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/Packages.html) - Written by the man himself!

Comment: Sorry, meant to add the __init__.py. um... why is there one in the package root? Also thanks ;)

Comment: Your right according to the docs - you don't need it under all circumstances; BUT I've ALWAYS done it...  Reference :http://docs.python.org/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-package

Answer (score 1):

```
import core.hash.hashgen
```

Alternatively, for shorter, but potentially confusing code:

```
from core.hash import hashgen
# Don't forget hashgen now refers to a foreign module
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from package.core.hash import hashgen
```

Your code should be in PYTHONPATH and you should have `__init__.py` files